# Distorted black area with Intel GMA 950

Tags: 16.04, drivers, graphics

Recently tried to install (L)Ubuntu 16 on an old HP 2140 which has an Intel GMA 950 graphics card. After installation, I see the attached desktop. Notice that most of the screen (top-left portion) is black and/or garbled.

[image: Screen shot]

Note: The (GUI) linux installer looked fine so I guess it should be possible to make it work without the strange distorted area...

Answer (score 0):

After searching for similar problems, I happened upon a solution. Apparently in more recent kernel versions, this video card is not properly supported by default. One needs to add the following boot parameter:

```
i915.lvds_use_ssc=0
```

Allows the system to boot correctly.

See: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/925350